# How to setup Git mirror for big SVN repository?

Tags: git, github, svn, version-control, git-svn

I have SVN repository. At various point of time, People checked in big files in this SVN repository ( > 100 MB ). We have enterprise Github. It does not support objects more than 50 MB (That's our configuration, we are one of 100 other projects using this Github instance)

We have created git clone using git-svn. When we pushed this git to Github, it complained about the error. We removed all big objects using [BFG Repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). We were able to push this git to Github.

Now the question is how to update this git to to keep it in sync with SVN. BFG modified all commit IDs so git-svn does not work properly. We have git clone in other directory, when we merge from this git, it brings all old files back, even if they are deleted from current SVN HEAD.

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: https://git-lfs.github.com/ might help you ?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to make this work properly. Maybe besides having an unmodified `git-svn` history in one set of remotes and another cleaned history and then you have to use rebasing to copy commits from one history to the other manually.

Comment: You need to sync git with svn manually by `git svn fetch` or rebase. Or you can schedule to run the script with the git svn command and `git push` intermittently.

Comment: To my knowledge, git-svn uses not the commit hashes, but the `git-svn-id` lines in the commit messages. What happens if you try to update the cleaned git repository from SVN?